# Are my Objective-C singletons thread safe?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, singleton

I've been reading around and its hard to get a clear feel if I have written a thread safe implementation here.

My getter looks like

```
+ (MySingleton *)getSingleton
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        singleton = [[MySingleton alloc] init];
    });
    return singleton;
}
```

And my setter is:

```
+ (void)updateSingleton:(MySingleton *)newSingleton
{
    @syncronized(self) {
        singleton = newSingleton;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of `updateSingleton`?

Answer (score 2):

No, that isn't thread safe.  Your exclusion mechanism between your two modification methods are not the same.   `dispatch_once` has nothing to do with `@synchronized` in any way.

Beyond that a singleton **must never be replaced** by definition.   A singleton can come into existence at any time and, once it does, it never, **ever**, goes away.

Also, `getSingleton` should be `sharedInstance` or some similar objective-c standard moniker.  Methods should never be prepended with `get` unless they are returning stuff by reference.